# Passing const QByteArray to overloaded function

Tags: c++, qt, overloading

I have following overloaded function

```
void testFun(QByteArray& arr){
    QTextStream out(stdout);
    out << "QByte" << endl;
}

void testFun(QString str){
    QTextStream out(stdout);
    out << "QStr" << endl;
}
```

Why function `void testFun(QString str)` is called if I use `const QByteArray` as argument.

It means - this block of code:

```
QByteArray bA("aaa");
const QByteArray bB(bA);

testFun(bA);
testFun(bB);
```

gives following output:

```
QByte
QStr
```

Comment: Because `testFun(QByteArray& arr)` assumes that `arr` can be modified by function, however your `bB` object cannot. Therefore compiler calls the most appropriate overload which is `testFun(QString str)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the first overload takes a non-const `QByteArray`, it does not get used.

C++ has a feature called [Converting Constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor). This means that a single-argument constructor that is not marked as `explicit` can be used automatically to convert one type into another for function overload resolution.

`QString` has [such a constructor](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#QString-8) that takes a `const QByteArray&`. Therefore, when selecting what function overload to use, the compiler can first convert the `QByteArray` to a `QString` using that constructor, and then proceed to pass that `QString` into your second function.

Please see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying cause is that Qt (and by extension: you!) allows writing non-typesafe code: there's an implicit conversion from `QByteArray` to `QString`. Define `QT_RESTRICTED_CAST_FROM_ASCII` project-wide, wipe the build folder and rebuild the project. The call that uses the const object won't compile then, and you'll have to fix the function signatures: you should have been taking const references all along.

```
void testFun(const QByteArray &arr){
    QTextStream out(stdout);
    out << "QByte" << endl;
}

void testFun(const QString &str) {
    QTextStream out(stdout);
    out << "QStr" << endl;
}
```